How can I perform elementary row operations on this polynomial matrix to transform it into the identity matrix?
Given that
$$
a(x)f(x) + b(x)g(x) = 1,
\boldsymbol{A}(x) := \begin{pmatrix}
a(x) & b(x) \\
- g(x) & f(x)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
According to the theory of canonical forms for polynomial matrices, since all invariant factors of $ \boldsymbol{A}(x) $ are $1$, $ \boldsymbol{A}(x) $ is equivalent to the identity matrix. However, how can one explicitly perform elementary transformation steps (i.e., row and column operations) to transform $ \boldsymbol{A}(x) $ into $ \boldsymbol{I}_{2 \times 2} $?

In general,$$\pmatrix{a & b \ c & d}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad - bc}\pmatrix{d & -b \ -c & a}.$$

In terms of the explicit row operations, nothing really changes, except you should avoid division. You could start by multiplying the top row by $g(x)$, and the bottom row by $a(x)$. Then you can add the top row to the bottom.

No, this approach is not feasible. Elementary operations on polynomial matrices only allow multiplication of a row/column by constants, not by arbitrary polynomials.

Assuming these are real or complex polynomials, you could consider the matrix individually for each $x$. That way, you only ever deal with a matrix of real or complex numbers. The same steps would work, producing the identity matrix. It would then give you an inverse matrix in terms of polynomials. But, I'm not really sure why you think this procedure is not feasible. Sure, you may be used to this process only in fields, but that doesn't mean it can't work in more general circumstances.

This is because ultimately I want to express matrix A(x) as a product of invertible elementary polynomial matrices. However, if x is taken as a zero of g(x), then multiplying the first row by g(x) = 0 would not be an invertible operation.

For the sake of a little more symmetry, consider the matrix of polynomials
$$\pmatrix{a(x) & b(x) \\ c(x) & d(x)}$$
with determinant $\pm 1$, i.e. $a(x)d(x) - b(x)c(x) = 1$ for all $x$, or $a(x)d(x) - b(x)c(x) = -1$ for all $x$. Now, I will prove, by induction on $\deg c$, that every such matrix is a product of elementary matrices. By repeatedly applying the induction step, you can recover all the elementary matrices used in the product.
We will also impose an additional restriction: let us suppose $\deg a \ge \deg c$. If this is not the case, then we replace the matrix with
$$\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} = \pmatrix{c & d \\ a & b}.$$
So, we may assume without loss of generality that $\deg a \ge \deg c$.
Let's examine our base case: assume $\deg c = -1$, i.e. $c = 0$. We then have $ad = \pm1$, which implies $a$ and $d$ are both constants, and non-zero ones at that. As such, in this case, we can express the matrix as a product elementary matrices:
$$\pmatrix{a & b(x) \\ 0 & d} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & d}\pmatrix{a & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\pmatrix{1 & a^{-1}b(x) \\ 0 & 1}.$$
This establishes the base case.
Assume we have $n \ge -1$ such that any such matrix can be expressed as the product of elementary matrices, so long as $\deg c < n$. Suppose now that our matrix has $\deg c = n$.
We now divide $c$ into $a$, a la Euclid's algorithm. We know there exist a partial quotient polynomial $q$, and a remainder polynomial $r$ satisfying $\deg r < \deg c$. We then have
$$a = qc + r.$$
Therefore:
$$\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}\pmatrix{1 & -q \\ 0 & 1}\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} = \pmatrix{c & d \\ r & b-qd}.$$
The matrix on the right hand side has an entry in the bottom left of degree $\deg r < \deg c = n$. By the multiplicativity of the determinant, we also have
$$\det \pmatrix{c & d \\ r & b-qd} = - \det \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d} = \pm 1.$$
By the induction hypothesis, we can write $\pmatrix{c & d \\ r & b-qd}$ as a product of elementary matrices, which proves $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$ is also expressible as a product of elementary matrices, by induction.
Obviously, to find these elementary matrices, you'd need to perform Euclid's algorithm on the particular polynomials found in the left column!

This idea is indeed correct and aligns with the proofs commonly found in textbooks.
I initially thought there might be some simple formula, but I later abandoned this notion because if such a straightforward method existed, textbooks would have replaced the repeated application of the Euclidean algorithm with this elegant formula.

I had a bit of a play around with it, finding a more general algorithm that would work in a free commutative ring, and I also suspect that there is no such method.
